# I need to get a value from an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

With Javascript how can I get the id of each object in this kind of object:

```
array = [
    { active: false, defaultTag:true, id: '507f191e810c19729de860ea', title: 'one' },
    { active: false, defaultTag:true, id: '507f191e810c19722de860ea', title: 'two' }
];
```

I need to fetch the id in order to check if the item already exists in the array whe a use intent to save the same object again.

Best regards
Americo

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied, aren't searchable for future readers and harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865)

Comment: That was a screenshot from the Firefox console, I will try to write the same as code

Answer (score 0):

here you can get array of unique ids

```
 var unique = [],
 tmp, i = 0;
 while(i < array.length){
   unique.indexOf(tmp = array[i++].id) > -1 ? array.pop(i--) : unique.push(tmp)
 }
 console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Gather all your items under one object using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). This will filter out duplicates
2. Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values inside your object. The returned value is the filtered array

```js
const array = [
    { active: false, defaultTag:true, id: '507f191e810c19729de860ea', title: 'duplicateOne' },
    { active: false, defaultTag:true, id: '507f191e810c19729de860ea', title: 'one' },
    { active: false, defaultTag:true, id: '507f191e810c19722de860ea', title: 'two' }
];

const removeDupsById = arr => Object.values(
  arr.reduce((a, c) => ({...a, [c.id]: c}), {})
);

console.log(removeDupsById(array));
```